# How to get a value using specified key?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

There is an array created out of JSON source with use of `$.each` method. This is what the console says:

```
$vm0.sailNames;
[Array(24), __ob__: Observer]
```

(for some reason, jQuery created an Observer)

In the Vue.js dev view it looks this way:
[image: Vue.js View]

How can I get `displayName` value passing `name` as an argument? Is there any Vue.js arrays way to do this?

-- edit: adding some markup:

```
data() {
    return {
      (...)
      sailNames: [],
      (...)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    someMethod(name) {
      console.log("sailNames: ", this.sailNames);
      let item = this.sailNames.find(s => s.name == name);
      console.log("name (someMethod's arg.): ", name);
      console.log("item: ", item);

    },
    showName: function(e) { // this is the function triggered @click
      (...)
      const sourceElement = e.target.id;
      this.someMethod(sourceElement);
      (...)
    },
    (...)
```

Console outputs on DOM element click:

```
sailNames:  [Array(24), __ob__: Observer]
name (someMethod's arg.):  grot
item:  undefined`
```

DOM elements in the template:

```
<svg>
(...)
    <g id="sailShapes">
        <path class="rope" d="M 15,589 395,94" />
        <path id="latacz" d="M 160,404 255,391 390,104 z" class="sail" @click="showName" />
        <path class="rope" d="M 30,592 395,179" />
        <path id="grot" d="M 100,519 285,490 330,254 z" class="sail" @click="showName" />
    (...)
    </g>
(...)
</svg>
```

Comment: jQuery didn't create an observer, Vue converts data into observed values. Just use vanilla javascript. Where do you want to use it? In a method? A template?

Comment: "sailNames" are defined within data, then updated by jQuery's $.each method. After the array is filled in, I'm trying to use its values in a method triggered by a click on a DOM element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the object.

```
methods:{
  someMethod(name){
    let item=  this.sailNames.find(s => s.name == name)
    if (!item)
      //error

    // use item.displayName in code
  }
}
```

But also, typically if you are rendering `sailNames` in your template, you can just pass the entire object to your method.

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in sailNames" @click="someMethod(item)">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

and your `someMethod` becomes

```
someMethod(item){
  //use item.displayName
}
```

**Edit**

For future readers, there was a small bug in the way `sailNames` was being populated that caused the above methods to not work. With that fixed, everything flew.

Comment: For some reason, the "item" keeps being undefined. There are console.logs in someMethod()'s body that display sailNames array in the correct shape, also the "name" parameter is read correctly, but the "item" variable is still undefined in the end. I chose the first option, without v-for in the template.

Comment: @AbreQueVoy if you share your code I can look it over.

Comment: added some code into the question's body, please take a look.

Comment: @AbreQueVoy Can you add the template that uses `sailNames`?

Comment: The triggering elements are SVG shapes, example added above. Please let me know if it's sufficient.